# Django forms with variable user entries

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I want to create a django form that captures user entry such as `name`, `address`, `age`. For this type of information I can create a model such as

```
class GeneralUserInfo(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField()
    lastname = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    # etc....
```

However, I also want to capture maybe some information like their class schedule or family information.

```
class UserSchedule(models.Model):
    course_number = model.IntegerField()
    course_name = model.CharField()
    # etc....

class FamilyInfo(models.Model):
    family_member_type = models.CharField(choices = MEMBER_CHOICES) # mother, father, sibling
    family_member_name = models.CharField() # jon doe
    # etc....
```

where by each user, the number of courses and number of family members could vary.

I would like the form to look something like below

[image: Form Example]

with a simple submit button to send things off to be saved.

**My question is**, how should I structure the form template considering there are multiple models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the above question can take a couple of forms. I'll rewrite the example above to add more context.

Say there's a student, Ashley, with college course work (say she's taking 4 course) and with family (mom, pop, sis, bro). I'd like to capture all this information for Ashley. So I've written the following `models.py`

```
class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField()
    lastname = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    # etc....

class Course(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(GeneralUserInfo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    course_number = model.IntegerField()
    course_name = model.CharField()
    # etc....

class Family(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(GeneralUserInfo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    family_member_type = models.CharField(choices = MEMBER_CHOICES) # mother, father, sibling
    family_member_name = models.CharField() # jon doe
    # etc....
```

Next, what is needed is to use [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/models/) inside your views.

You could potentially have two views in `views.py`. One that creates the student, and another that edits the information belonging to that student.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import StudentForm
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Student, Course, Family



@login_required
def createstudent(request):
    context = {'studentform': StudentForm}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit = False) # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h57cqFRcqg
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Saved new contact!")
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'mainapp/createstudent.html', context)



@login_required
def editview(request, id):
    student = Student.objects.get(pk = id)
    CourseFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Student, Course, fields = ('name', 'skill'), extra=5, max_num=5)
    FamilyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Student, Family, fields = ('name', 'skill'), extra=5, max_num=5)

    if request.method == "POST":
        courseformset = CourseFormSet(request.POST, instance = contact)
        Familyform = FamilyFormSet(request.POST, instance = contact)
        if courseformset.is_valid():
            courseformset.save()
        if Familyform.is_valid():
            Familyform.save()
        if courseformset.is_valid() or Familyform.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, "Saved new information")
            return redirect('editview', id=id)

    courseformset = CourseFormSet(instance = contact)
    Familyform = FamilyFormSet(instance = contact)
    context = {'courseformset': courseformset, 'title': 'Edit View', 'Familyform': Familyform}
    return render(request, 'mainapp/editview.html', context)
```

Then inside an edit view template, `editview.html`

```
{% extends "mainapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}


    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <br>
    <h5>Edit the form below</h5>
    <br>


    <form method = "POST">
    <br>
    <h2>Courses</h2>
    <br>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ courseformset.management_form }}
        {% for form in courseformset %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </div>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}

    <br>
    <h2>Family</h2>
    <br>
        {{ Familyform.management_form }}
        {% for form in Familyform %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </div>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is just an example. However, for a whole project *example*, please see: https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/onlineforms-project/